# Extracting mass amounts of column and rows using python from a CSV?

Tags: python

I have mass amounts of data in a csv file which needs to be extracted.

The table contains over 5000+ columns and 1000+ rows
For example, the data may look like

```
Name height age sports sex etc.
Jim  5'4   21   fb    M   etc.
Bob  5'7   22   bb    F   etc.
Amy  etc.
Mike etc.
etc. etc.
```

I need to extract columns and rows which satisfy a condition. So for example, I may need to extract all rows and their data for the columns height and age. Sports/sex/etc. should not be extracted.

The code I have written is something like this

```
with open('filepath') as file:
   writer = csv.writer(file)
       for row in csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=','):
           for col in row:
               if 'age' in col:
                  print(col, row[col])
```

It is only extracting 1 value from each row at a time, whereas I need to extract every value in each row where the column is needed.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you considered pandas?

Comment: Yes, I have attempted to use pandas but the library is still pretty foreign to me.

Comment: you should get into it though, man

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you read each row separately and search for the expected value in that row. To print every value in such a row, you would simply have to:

```
print(row)
```

instead of

```
print(row[col])
```

since that will obviously only return one value, as row is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I've tried this already. It prints the whole row whereas I only need specific columns from the row.

Comment: You need multiple columns from the same row but only search for one value, don't you have to add more search parameters?

Comment: Yes, I do. The code above was just an example. The main issue I'm having is extracting the value associated with that specific column for every row.

Comment: Then the problem with your code is probably that col is a value and not an index, calling row[col] doesn't return anything, so it only prints col.

Comment: The code works fine for me, it prints the correct value. The issue is printing it all on a line where all required values are extracted.

Comment: So the problem is that the values are printed on different lines? You could just use print(col, row[col], end=""), so that it doesn't print a \n. Then at the end of the inner loop you just use print() so it adds a newline.